# auto page breaks when printing long pages with ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing, rubygems

I have a rails app that creates quotations with information and images on that can be very different in size and the data they display.

Each quote contains many setions of varying sizes.

I need to find a way to auomatically put page breaks into the quote when printing so that none of th sections are cut into printing on 2 pages.

Any ideas or experience with this would be great

thanks alot
rick

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `page-break-before`and `page-break-after` CSS properties:

```
<br style='page-break-after: always'>
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_print_pageba.asp) for caveats and notes.

Comment: Pekka

yes this is what i will use but i have to add this dynamically if a section will not fit on the current page,  i can't just assin this to all sections as they would appear each on its own page.   I have to work out the height of the section and if it will fit on the remaining space on the current page - if not put onto next page and so on..

any ideas ?

Comment: That is going to be difficult using HTML/CSS, because it is very hard to reliably find out the remaining space. Maybe you can work with a combination of ´<tables>´ with `page-break-after: avoid`?